# Special way of forming regex?

Tags: regex

I've come across this regex and I was wondering how this is used:

```
^.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$
```

I want to know what the individual section of the regex mean, not only what the regex in its whole does.

With the knowledge of regex's I have, I think it matches for any input (at least 10 chars long) that matches a digit (0-9), lowercase and uppercase letters, but I need confirmation if this is correct?

**Edit**

I also don't know what it is meant to validate, but looking at what I think it does, is it right that the regex can be simplified to:

```
[\d|[a-zA-Z]]{10,}
```

**Edit 2**
I've noticed my replacement regex doesn't make sure I have at least one of every requirements (at least a digit, upcase and lowcase letter). Any way to adjust it so the regex does that as well, or is that only possible with the original regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can explain what the parts of the regex do, but in general I find this quite odd:

```
^.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$
```

Basically what you said is true - there is no other magic in the regex.

`^.*` - match the beginning of the line and 0+ characters then ensure that

The following just assert - none of them matches/captures anything. It's called the positive lookahead if you want to look it up. if all of them evaluate to true, the last part of the regex will do the rest:

`(?=.{10,})` - from where the first matching stops (could be after the beginning of the line) there is a string of 10+ chars (any chars)

`(?=.*\d)` - and there is at least one digit in the whole string ahead

`(?=.*[a-z])` - and a lower case letter

`(?=.*[A-Z])` - and an upper case letter

If all that is true, then:

`.*$` - match everything till the end of the line

Note: if any of the asserts fail, nothing will be matched.

**To your edit**

I don't think so - it's not the same to say that there is an upper and lower case letter and a digit somewhere in the string, and to say that the string consists of 10+ characters of which all are either digits or letters (upper or lower case) or both. Your regex would match a string that consists of only digits as well as only letters or a mix of both - the original regex ensures that each of these classes is represented at least once. It seems that someone might have used it to validate a user password or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably used to validate candidate passwords - it

1. Checks that it is at least 10 characters long
2. Checks that it contains at least one digit
3. Checks that it contains at least one lower case letter
4. Checks that it contains at least one upper case letter

Your replacement regex is not identical because it just ORs the above conditions - the long nasty regex ANDs them. Also there is no order to the above conditions; the letters or digits can occur anywhere in the string.

I don't see a way of simplifying it much further actually - you might perhaps remove the .* at the beginning and .*$ at the end since they don't really serve any purpose. But otherwise, that long regex does a good job of conjunctively imposing those conditions without imposing an order.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is used for ensuring password strength:  it has to be at least 10 chars long, with at least 1 digit, at least 1 lowercase letter, and at least 1 uppercase letter.

The most important part of the whole regex is the `(?=...)` operator, which matches, but does NOT consume the part of the string it matches.  Multiple `(?=...)` next to one another, therefore, acts as an AND operator.

`(?=.{10,})` matches any sequence of at least 10 chars.

`(?=.*\d)` matches a single digit that follows anything.

`(?=.*[a-z])` matches a lowercase char that follows anything.

`(?=.*[A-Z])` matches an uppercase char that follows anything.

So this regex will match any string that has a substring that is at least 10-char long, has at least a digit, a lowercase char, and an uppercase char.

You can see that it sounds more complicated than it should, especially the substring part.  Indeed, the `.*` part right after `^` is not necessary, and we can simplify this as

```
^(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a password strength validation regex as others have said, but that `.*` at the beginning should not be there.  As it is, the `.*` initially consumes the whole string, then backtracks until it reaches a position where all four lookaheads can match.  It works, but why make the regex do so much work if it doesn't have to?

```
^(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$
```

With the leading `.*` removed, the regex *never* has to backtrack (unless you count returning to the starting position after a successful lookahead backtracking).  As for the `.*$` at the end, it might not be necessary, but it does no harm either.  I would leave it in, just in case someone tries to use the result of the match for something instead of the original string.

One more point: you could make the regex more concise by removing the first lookahead and putting the `.{10,}` in place of the `.*`:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{10,}$
```

The reason it's written the way it is, is to work around a long standing bug in Internet Explorer ([ref](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug)).   The bug finally got fixed in IE8 or IE9, but I would leave it the way it is, just in case.